# How to not to resize the content while using drawer in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a drawer like this in my project. As you can see when you expand the drawer the content resizes. But I don't want this. What I want is the expanded drawer to go over the content and not to resize it. How to solve this.
[image: Contracted drawer state]

### When expanded it becomes

[image: Expanded drawer state]

### I don't want this resizing of content.

> [Link to my code here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6xdsb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add position:'absolute' like this in demo.js. It will go over the content

```
drawer: {
    position:'absolute',
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  },
```

Also add marginLeft:80 to the content, so content will not go behind collapsed drawer.

```
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    marginLeft: 80
  }
```

Comment: I adjusted the theme spacing to account for margin